# Hadoop XML parsing - Sqoop and pig/hive/MR

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, sqoop

The source database has a table with a bunch of columns and one of the columns is a CLOB that contains the XML.

The requirement is to sqoop this table into HDFS and explode this raw data into multiple files. Hive tables may have to be created on top of these files.

I am trying to understand the best possible solution interms of performance etc., to achieve the same. I narrowed down the following options

1. MR job which reads the xml column (using XPath or some xml parsing FW) and the other columns too, stores into multiple files based on the needs.
2. Using Pig XPath UDF
3. Using xmlSerde (com.ibm.spss.... package)

> Q1. Any thoughts on these options and any other option would help?
>
> For option 2, I dont think XMLLoader can be used as it expects the
>   underlying file to have XML not the other columns.
>   Q2. Am i right here?
>
> Q3. Even if its only the XML, can i handle multiple XMLs (same
>   structure though) in the same file?